# Помогите распарсить массив в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, json

Как, используя `С++`, распарсить приведенный ниже `json` и вытащить из него массивы?

```
"map": [
        [1, 2, 44421, "Best Of The Best", 1456586881, 19, 0, 0, 0, [
                [4487962, "Mark.Howard", 62781, 2],
                [3078674, "Наглый_Лжец", 38015, 2],
                [1473816, "CheRRy Rayn", 36781, 2],
                [6318344, "Shapia", 25524, 2],
                [6049787, "Рафашка 2", 23546, 2],
                [1915781, "Katakur", 21965, 2],
                [4747634, "Zavistb", 21187, 2],
                [2813170, "TopLine", 19021, 2],
                [5570609, "YuiNyan San", 18130, 2],
                [4782195, "little crow", 18024, 2]
            ],
            [
                [3487, "Gold Winners", 65374, 2],
                [6632, "True Blood", 61346, 2],
                [1269, "Oops Sorry", 52049, 2],
                [8436, "Crazy CheRRy", 48245, 2],
                [44421, "Best Of The Best", 46242, 2],
                [29294, "Rhythmic Beasts", 46067, 2],
                [50634, "С е м ь Я", 43654, 2],
                [77, "Dream Team", 35584, 2],
                [53668, "Тихий омут", 31462, 2],
                [23459, "АНГЕЛЫ СМЕРТИ", 24420, 2]
            ],
            [], ""
        ],
        [2, 1, 37381, "Fa11out", 1456678654, 53, 0, 0, 0, [
                [5013531, "Алкоша", 32235, 2],
                [4418909, "покаяние", 23978, 2],
                [5491860, "оНеМоЙо", 9138, 2],
                [2175346, "Edvin Pirs", 6591, 2],
                [4364094, "peliby", 6260, 2],
                [3156999, "Оболдевший", 5716, 2],
                [5996907, "net_014", 5214, 2],
                [6404932, "вася1986ф", 4993, 2],
                [3163010, "боликс", 4625, 2],
                [2680928, "vandam92", 4535, 2]
            ],
            [
                [62424, "The Gre4ka", 39994, 2],
                [51699, "Твори Добро", 37365, 2],
                [11413, "Гладиаторы улиц", 29781, 2],
                [41114, "dark Territory", 15405, 2],
                [64698, "Мы с УРАЛА", 12349, 2],
                [16606, "Russia Stars", 11918, 2],
                [60927, "Рюмочная", 9138, 2],
                [26376, "WakaWaka and Darkzen", 4759, 2],
                [64400, "Hell on Earth", 3736, 3],
                [38725, "Never give up", 3447, 2]
            ],
            [], ""
        ],
```

Comment: в чем проблема?

Comment: Приведите код попытки сделать это.

Answer (score 1):

Для разбора json воспользуйтесь уже готовыми библиотеками. Например, [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).